# using char data in a switch statement

Tags: java, arrays, char, switch-statement

I'm trying to get a case statement to add an integer to an integer array using char data pulled from a string.

```
int x = SString.length() - 1;
int[] values = new int[x + 1];
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    System.out.println(keyword.charAt(i));
    switch (SString.charAt(i)) {
        case 'a':
            values[i] = 0;
        case 'b':
            values[i] = 1;
        case 'c':
            values[i] = 2;
            System.out.println(values[i]);
    }
}
```

my expected output for a when `SString = abc` is `values = {0,1,2}`. Instead, `values = {2,2,2}`.

Comment: Switches require `break` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `break` statements.

```
switch (SString.charAt(i)) {
case 'a':
    values[i] = 0;
    break;
case 'b':
    values[i] = 1;
    break;
case 'c':
    values[i] = 2;  
    break;
}
```

Comment: I feel like an absolute idiot. I've been staring at this for like 3 hours and that never once even crossed my mind.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the break in each case statment, so all cases fall through and eventually all end up with `values[i] = 2;`

```
switch(SString.charAt(i)){
  case 'a':
    values[i] = 0;
    break; // this one for each
  case 'b':
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot break statement and System.out should be outside of switch statement.

```
    String SString = "abc";
    int x = SString.length() - 1;
    int[] values = new int[x + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        switch (SString.charAt(i)) {
            case 'a':
                values[i] = 0;
                break;
            case 'b':
                values[i] = 1;
                break;
            case 'c':
                values[i] = 2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        System.out.print(values[i] + " ");
    }
```

Output: 0 1 2